# Ajax jquery with class form by Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 forms, each with same class and each will execute ajax jquery. I try to send Ajax in below code, but it is sending request for each form.

```
var form = $(".forms");

form.submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Servlet',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      to: $(".param1 option:selected").val(),
      from:  $(".param2 option:selected").val(),
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      alert("worked");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(jqXHR+" : "+textStatus+" : "+errorThrown);
    }
  });
})
```

here are jsp code

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="3" var="i">
            <div>
                <form method="post" class="forms" action="Servlet" name="forumlario-${i}" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <div>
                        <select class="param1" name="param1">
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select class="param2" name="param2">
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                        </select>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" value="calcular" id="calcular" >calcular</button> 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

how get just specific form submited that was clicked and execute ajax?

i dont find the solution and get form by atributte name now

```
//attribute form 1 = name="forums-1"
//attribute form 3 = name="forums-2"
//attribute form 2 = name="forums-3"
```

then the solution that i find is replay code 3x

```
$('[name="forums-1"]').submit(function() {
                //code omitted
 });
$('[name="forums-2"]').submit(function() {
                //code omitted
});
$('[name="forums-3"]').submit(function() {
                //code omitted
});
```

but dont are clean code, how i should to do for make just 1 statement for both form

Comment: What is your expected behavior then? The code works as it's supposed to work.

Comment: i have 3 form in same page with same class when i click in submit from a form, fail, because with this code is required i fill all forms, mean all forms is going submit in same time,i wanted get just action from form that was clicked

Comment: 3 questions: Do you have a button per form? If so, is there any code to them? Can you show us the html of your forms?

Comment: @Ric Please provide the whole HTML with 3 forms,

Answer (score 1):

You have changed your question a number of times, so therefore the answer keeps changing.

> how get just specific form submited that was clicked and execute ajax?

To get the specific form entity of the three that was submitted, you can do so WITHIN the `.submit(function() {})` using `this`. The `this` variable will represent the specific form, of the three `.forms` that were submitted. Then you can perform the necessary functions based on the returned `this`

```
form.submit(function() {
  $(this); //represents the SPECIFIC form that was submitted
});
```

Comment: this part i know. but how i will use "this" in this context? i make this form.submit(function() {
  $(this).submit(function() {                                                                   //omitted code
});    but are exactly what i want know

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you properly, the ajax is not being sent. You should try adding return false to the function passed to submit to prevent the forms from doing their default behavior and instead make the AJAX request

```
form.submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Servlet',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      to: $("#param1 option:selected").val(),
      from:  $("#param2 option:selected").val(),
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      alert("worked");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(jqXHR+" : "+textStatus+" : "+errorThrown);
    }
  });
  return false;
})
```

Comment: no, i want get specific submit form , from this class that have 3 element, the return false i put in tag <form>